# Nextjs App how to handle local data storage after querying with Firestore?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, state, browser-cache

I'm developing a react e-commerce app with Firestore database. When the app loads it fetches first 50 products (each one is a Firestore doc), and renders the product card with the data. My question is where to store this data for easy access in case of page refresh, navigation to say to order page and come back to the products page, close the tab and open again etc.

I'm asking this because when I monitor my Firestore usage for following;

1. I open products page and load 50 products, go to second page load another 50 etc.
2. Do filtering get another 50 products, remove filters, get the first 50 products again.
3. Go to orders page come back get 50 products.

All in all one session can easily reach thousands of doc reads, lots of data use and longer load times. So I think I`m missing a point here. There should be a way to store all these data without making the app slower and data usage more expensive. What would be a good approach here to save the data in session and full refresh, close the tab and come back etc. ?

P.S. I'm using Next.js and Firestore, data fetching is done on the client side via Firestore web library.

Comment: Have you considered using [pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) or [limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) the data you receive from your queries to the Firestore Instance. Additionally I believe that you could find the 
[offline persistence feature](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) to be useful.

Comment: @DanielOcando Thanks for your reply, the data is already paginated and limited, hence the reason why 50 reads occur for each refresh or navigation. Offline persistence, caching, is indeed very useful that`s a good way to store the document data, but what about non document data like images and etc, those are done by urlfetch not firestore, any ideas ?

Comment: What exactly are you using to get non document data? Google's URLfetch libs (e.g. [1](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#advanced-parameters) or [2](https://www.learngoogle.com/tag/urlfetch/)) are usually optimized for efficiency and scaling and let you set the header fields [related to cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) where you could tune your application regarding if the fetch is done to the servers or the cache. Be aware that careless tuning of such headers can lead to your app not updating correctly.

Comment: @DanielOcando What I do is, store img location as url within the doc field, and pass that url into image property of the html element, so I assume it renders using the link everytime a refresh occurs. Do you think there occurs an auto caching and I should leave it as it is or if not where should I put set the header fields ?

Comment: Given the way you are displaying your image besides the usual image optimization techniques (resizing, changing quality, adapting for mobile applications and making them lighter in general), using an image CDN, or use lazy loading I don't believe there is much else to be done to optimize that aspect of your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you get the data from firebase simply store it over local storage as follows,

considering you get the data of component load like in a useEffect and store it in a state name as product. Now my approach would be to look for any update in product variable through useEffect and simply update the local storage

```
const [product,setproduct] = useState([]); // containing array of product
useEffect(() => {
   if(product.length>0) localStorage.setItems('products',JSON.stringify(product));
  }, [product]);
```

That way you have it on localstorage and use it anywhere around the application. Also in other components while calling firestore to get product make sure to check local storage first. If there is already some data stored over local storage, dont go up for calling firestore to get data.

That will reduce you API calls and along side increase the performance of the application.

Voila! I hope it solves your purpose. :)

Comment: Hi @rakshit-maini,

Thank you for your answer, I ended up using a very similar approach. Although since I needed a more centralized data storage, I did create a React Context and read & write the data from cache, access it from within context. I also made it in a way that when the user logged out, the data is removed from the cache. I think local storage is another alternative, but do you think that is actually better ?

Thanks again!

Comment: Yea right, that definitely is another good approach to hung up on.